# How to add synonyms to websolr in heroku dynamically

Tags: heroku, synonym, websolr

Is there any way, that we can add synonyms dynamically to websolr in heroku.

Now we can add synonyms only by accessing the websolr page and changing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Websolr support here. Unfortunately Websolr doesn't provide a mechanism to update synonyms programmatically. We have discussed rolling out that capability in a future update, but at this time there are no concrete plans.